Converting a Rush Monorepo from create-react-app to vite
I am working on converting over this rush monorepo to vite but am having issues with aliasing linked packages.
In my case, my folder structure is as follows
Project

apps

frontend
backend


packages

api-types



In my package.json for my frontend, I have this
 "dependencies": {
  "@projectName/api-types": "workspace:*",
}

Now in my vite config, to get the aliases working I have added
resolve: {
    alias: {
 "@projectName/api-types": path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        "../../packages/api-types/build/index.js"
      ),}

Running into this error on vite build
src/containers/actionItems/helpers.ts (9:9): "type" is not exported by "../../packages/api-types/build/index.js"

and the build file looks like this
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
__exportStar(require("./account"), exports);

where the correct type does live under the nested import
Things I've tried
updating tsconfig with a path, adding this dependency to optimizeDeps in my vite config, adding this to build/commonJsOptions in vite config

Something that may be relevant, it seems like all my enums fail.

And as it turns out --- the issue was in my tsconfig in my linked package... make sure both tsconfigs are targeting the same module
adding
 "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "esnext"
    ```
fixed it :)

